# Remove whitespaces before a character starts and before equal to(=) sign and using shell

Tags: shell

I have one file(file1.txt)

```
Rahul=rahul

Vimal=vimal

   Vishal =vishal

   Rupesh =rupesh

   Aromal =aromal

   Anugrah =anugrah
```

My output file should be

```
Rahul=rahul

Vimal=vimal

Vishal=vishal

Rupesh=rupesh

Aromal=aromal

Anugrah=anugrah
```

I tried with following commands. Still not getting output as I needed.

```
sed 's/  */ /g' < file1.txt

sed 's/ \{1,\}/ /g' < file1.txt

sed 's/ \+ / /g' < file1.txt

sed -e "s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g" < file1.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `sed` with an alternation in your regex:

```
sed -E 's/^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+(=)/\1/g' file
```

`\1` is back-reference for capture group #1 i.e. `=` in 2nd part of alternation.

```
Rahul=rahul

Vimal=vimal

Vishal=vishal

Rupesh=rupesh

Aromal=aromal

Anugrah=anugrah
```

Comment: Hello Anubhava. Thanks for the quick response. I got the output what i needed.

Comment: Hello Anubhava, I have one doubt. Just consider I have white spaces before and after "=".(for example, Rupesh = rupesh) How do I remove that?

Comment: @RupeshMadhav: Try this: `sed -E 's/^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]*(=)[[:blank:]]*/\1/g' file`

Answer (score 0):

You can use shell `tr` command if not required to use sed:

```
tr -d ' ' < file1.txt
```

Hope this helps